# brew install python fails with AttributeError

Tags: python, homebrew

`brew install python` fails with

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BufferedIOBase'
```

does anyone have any idea what this means?

the full output is below:

```
==> Downloading http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.3/Python-2.7.3.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/python-2.7.3.tar.bz2
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3 --enable-ipv6 --dataroot
==> make
==> make install PYTHONAPPSDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3
==> make frameworkinstallextras PYTHONAPPSDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/sha
==> Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/distribute/distribute-0
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/distribute-0.6.30.tar.gz
==> /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/bin/python -s setup.py --no-user-cfg install 
  File "/private/tmp/__UNKNOWN__-iM08/distribute-0.6.30/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 18, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File     "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 464, in <module>
    class ZipExtFile(io.BufferedIOBase):
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'BufferedIOBase'
```

Comment: I suspect there is a stray `io.py` file somewhere, perhaps in the current directory?

Comment: ok, so i should `grep -r io.py`? The thing is that the paths specified in the output don't exist once brew fails, as they were paths set up by the `brew install` process ... so i've not been sure where to look.

Comment: I have no idea what the current directory is when that fails.. There is one in the python 'lib/python2.7` path, that one is the correct module, but if there is a stray one in whatever is the current directory, then that could mask things and it would break in the way you reported.

Comment: so it'll only be a problem if it's in the current directory? I might `mkdir` and `cd` into a clean dir, and try there.

Comment: I'd have thought homebrew would change the current dir; try in a clean dir indeed. Note that this is *one* way that could cause these symptoms, so this is not guaranteed to fix your problem. Another might be a rogue `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: moving to a new directory didn't work. If you have time, i would appreciate some tips on how to check and clean the directory homebrew installs from, or how to weed my `PYTHONPATH`. i tried `echo $PYTHONPATH` but it's empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folks on the github / homebrew [suggested](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/16351) that i delete `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/`. After doing so, `brew install python` worked once again.